# The role of $\gamma$ & $C$ in SVM

Tags: svm, hyperparameter

I'm using support vector machine method with the Gaussian kernel. Is it true that $\gamma$ and $C$ are hyper parameters of SVM? What is their role exactly?

Answer (score 4):

Support vector machines with RBF kernel have the following objective function:

$$
\min_{\alpha, b, \xi} \frac{1}{2} \underbrace{\sum_{i\in SV}\sum_{j\in SV} \alpha_i \alpha_j y_i y_j \exp\big(-{\color{red}\gamma} \|\mathbf{x}_i-\mathbf{x}_j\|^2\big)}_{\|\mathbf{w}\|^2} + {\color{red}C}\sum_{i\in SV} \xi_i
$$

$C$ is a regularization parameter, which is used to control the tradeoff between model simplicity (low $\|\mathbf{w}\|^2$) and how well the model fits the data (low $\sum_{i\in SV} \xi_i$).

The kernel parameter $\gamma$ is used to control the locality of the kernel function. It varies between 0 and $\infty$ (in these limits the kernel matrix becomes the one matrix and unit matrix, respectively). Good values are somewhere in between.

It is crucial to optimize these parameters to obtain a good model. You can do that using many techniques, including grid search or software packages like [Optunity](http://www.optunity.net).